# Prove that if $a = bc+1$ then $(a,b) = 1$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I started by saying that there exists an $x,y$ such that $1 = ax +by$ but I really don't know where else to go with this. Any hints?

Comment: Once you know that there exists $x$ and $y$ so that $ax+by=1$, then the gcd divides $1$, but since $1$ is the smallest positive integer, you're done!

Comment: HINT: $1=a-bc$, so $(a,b)$ divides $1$.

Answer (score 3):

If $d$ is any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ then it also divides their difference $a-b$. Then also the difference of $a-b$ and $b$ thus $a-2b$. Continuing like this, we get that $d$ is a common divisor of all integers $a-\kappa b$, for any integer $\kappa$. Thus, $d$ will be a divisor of $a-bc=1$. Consequently, $d=1$. Thus, $(a,b)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you find two integers $x$ and $y$ such that $1=ax+by$, you can conclude that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Indeed, if some integer $d>0$ divides both $a$ and $b$, we have
$$
a=du,\quad b=dv
$$
so
$$
1=ax+by=d(ux+vy)
$$
and therefore $d\mid 1$, hence $d=1$.

If you choose $x=1$ and $y=-c$, you have
$$
ax+by=a-bc=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if
$a_1a_2...a_n
=b_1b_2...b_m\pm 1
$,
then
$\gcd(a_i, b_j)
= 1
$
for every choice of
$i$ and $j$.

The proof is identical to
the others here:
If
$k$ divides both
$a_i$ and $b_j$,
then
$k$ divides
both
$a_1a_2...a_n$
and
$b_1b_2...b_m$
so that it
divides their difference
which is
$\pm 1$.

Even more generally,
if  $a_1a_2...a_n
=b_1b_2...b_m\pm c
$,
then
$\gcd(a_i, b_j)
$
divides
$c$
for every choice of
$i$ and $j$.

The proof is identical.